# How can I hide controls (not remove them from the DOM) on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, visibility

I have a div with `runat="server"` set. I have an ASP.NET button control in my page. When this button is clicked, I want to hide the div.

Is there any other option that setting `visible="false"`?

I can't use that, because when I do, I can't access the element in my JavaScript since it is removed from the browser. I want to show the hidden div with JavaScript at a later point.

Answer (score 6):

Add a `display:none` CSS style to the control:

```
myDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other option that
>   changing visibility to false.I cant
>   use the visibility to false,because
>   when i change visibility,I cant access
>   the same in my javascript since it is
>   removed from the browser.

This doesn't make sense.  Setting the CSS [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp) to hidden will not remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: He's talking about the visible property of an asp.net server or hybrid control.

Comment: Yes, but setting the visibility false in server side code (this.myDiv.Visible = false;) will remove it from the DOM.  I believe Shyju wants to avoid this, in which case I would use (this.myDiv.Style["display"] = "none";)

Comment: It is possible to set the CSS visibility property from the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the *only* thing your button does, I'd probably do it in javascript first to avoid the postback all together.

If that's not an option, then just add the style attribute to the div server-side with "`display:none;`" for the value.